# How to reference a library published in its artifacts feed from another project?

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have this project (A) in devops that builds and publishes a library(.jar) to the projects artifacts feed. Then I have this other project(B) where I have a Java application which references this library.

When running locally it works, it can connect to the repository and download the library, I have set up settings.xml so the authentication works to the feed.

But when running the build inside the pipeline which builds the java-application it is unable to find the artifact. First I got a 401 before realizing the maven-authenticate-task. After adding maven authenticate the 401 is gone but it keeps saying it cant find the artifact.

This is part of the log:

```
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact com.company.maximo-requests:maximo-requests:pom:0.0.81 from [ProjectCommon (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1, default, releases+snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1 with username=AzureDevOps, password=***
Downloading from ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/vsts/.m2/repository/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/vsts/.m2/repository/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom.lastUpdated
[WARNING] The POM for com.company.maximo-requests:maximo-requests:jar:0.0.81 is missing, no dependency information available
```

If I click the link to the pom in the log: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom it is downloaded in the browser, so the file exists.

And when running locally this is the log:

```
Resolving artifact com.company.maximo-requests:maximo-requests:pom:0.0.81 from [ProjectCommon (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1, default, releases+snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1 with username=CompanyDevOps, password=***
Downloading from ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom
Downloaded from ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom (3.6 kB at 1.8 kB/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\veriksso\.m2\repository\com\company\maximo-requests\maximo-requests\0.0.81\_remote.repositories
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\veriksso\.m2\repository\com\company\maximo-requests\maximo-requests\0.0.81\maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom.lastUpdated
```

The only difference I see is that username is AzureDevOps in the pipeline, probably generated by the maven authenticate task while the other one is a personal access token generated from within azure devops.

I have also added permissions to the feed in project A to the build service of project B according to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#pipelines-permissions.
[image]

But despite all this maven still outputs this at the end:

```
Failed to execute goal on project elinstallation: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.elinstallation:elinstallation:war:2.0.8-4-g0f575ca: Could not find artifact com.company.maximo-requests:maximo-requests:jar:0.0.81 in CompanyCommon (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/BolidenCommon/maven/v1) -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong? :'(

Update.
Here is Application B's Pom or at least the interesting parts I guess:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ....
    <dependencies>
        ......
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.maximo-requests</groupId>
            <artifactId>maximo-requests</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.81</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>CompanyCommon</id>
            <url>
                https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/CompanyCommon/maven/v1
            </url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

And here is library A's pom (interesting parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.maximo-requests</groupId>
    <artifactId>maximo-requests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.81</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>CompanyCommon</id>
            <url>
                https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/CompanyCommon/maven/v1
            </url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>CompanyCommon</id>
            <url>
                https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/CompanyCommon/maven/v1
            </url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

More Updates! pju this is a long post.

Here is the last output when building the library A:

```
Uploaded to ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.jar (122 kB at 97 kB/s)           
Uploaded to ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/0.0.81/maximo-requests-0.0.81.pom (3.6 kB at 3.5 kB/s)
Uploaded to ProjectCommon: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/CompanyDevOps/4a4b82f8-***/_packaging/ProjectCommon/maven/v1/com/company/maximo-requests/maximo-requests/maven-metadata.xml (2.6 kB at 31 kB/s)
```

Here is an excerpt of library A's pipeline:

```
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'CompanyCommon'
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    goals: 'package deploy'
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    options: '-DskipTests=true'
```

Here is an excerpt of application B's pipeline:

```
  - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    inputs:
     artifactsFeeds: 'CompanyCommon'    

  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
      mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
      effectivePomSkip: false
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

I have tried with both mavenAuthenticateFeed: true/false.

Comment: Can you share your pom?

Comment: Added the poms. I noticed that the username doesnt seem to be taken into consideration. I can change the username in settings.xml to whatever I want and it still works when build locally. I can even change it to AzureDevOps and it still works. I guess the password/token is what really matters.